# Modelling effect of renewable energy investment on GDP (via integrated assessment models)

Tags: mathematical-economics, reference-request, energy-economics, climate-change

I'm interested in modelling the effects of renewable energy investments and fossil fuel plant closures on the GDP using an energy-economy model of America's economy (eg. Nordhaus's RICE).

Any suggestions regarding the mathematical modelling aspects, or references (eg. papers) that are relevant? Currently I'm using this reference: "McKibbin, Morris, Wilcoxen, Cai: ``The Potential Role of a Carbon Tax in US fiscal reform"

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

A useful starting-point would be [Nordhaus's Nobel Prize Lecture](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/10/nordhaus-lecture.pdf), especially the sections headed Integrated Assessment Modelling and Mathematical Representation, and the references at the end of the Lecture.

For further details see the references at the end of the [Wikipedia article on  DICE model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICE_model), which include GAMS and Excel versions of the RICE model (references 20 and 23).

Comment: Thanks! The RICE paper is a good starting point: "A Regional Dynamic General-Equilibrium Model of Alternative Climate-Change Strategies". 
Are the DICE/RICE models available publicly? The links on Nordhaus's website are not working. https://williamnordhaus.com/dicerice-models

Comment: @PuraṭciVinnani  I've edited my answer to respond to the question in your comment.