# Adding an energy sector to Nordhaus's RICE model

Tags: general-equilibrium, energy-economics, climate-change

This is a follow-up question:
[Modelling effect of renewable energy investment on GDP (via integrated assessment models)](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52666/modelling-effect-of-renewable-energy-investment-on-gdp-via-integrated-assessmen/52670#52670)

I'm interested in adding an energy sector to Nordhaus's RICE model. Has there been any work in this direction? If not, are there are any references about adding an energy sector to general equilibrium models?

Here's a recent paper modifying the original RICE model (by Francis Dennig, Nested Inequalities Climate Economy), https://github.com/Environment-Research/NICE-MATLAB